How do I get 2 H1's on the same line?
I have a blog called mazeolog_, here is the troublesome code.
<h1>mazeolog</h1>
<h1 class="blink_me">_</h1>

I'm trying to get 2 h1's on the same line, but it isn't working. I looked at this for hours. He the code snippet.
TBH it's probably really easy (i'm new to HTML), but the best I got was it aligned on the left, but I forgot what i was using, but it goes something like this.
<h1 style="???: inline">...</h1>


You should read Accessible heading structure and change your markup.

You can use h1 { display: inline-block; } to achieve your desired result.

You could do <h1>mazeolog<span class="blink_me">_</span></h1> if you're willing to change the document structure slightly. This will integrate the underscore in to the first heading both visually and semantically. span is an inline element that can be used to select a portion of another tag's inner html.
